# Python - method inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, methods

If I have:

```
class Aclass(...):
    def get(self, a, b):
        #do something with a and b
```

, how can I make a `Bclass` and extend the get function? so in the get function of the Bclass I can do more computations with a and b

Hope you get the question, thank you

Comment: By reading the section on inheritance here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: I think you're missing a "self" argument to get -- that isn't a method as written that operates on an instance of Aclass.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Classes#Inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Aclass():
    def get(self, a, b):
        #do something with a and b

class Bclass(Aclass):
    def get(self, a, b):
        Aclass.get(self, a, b)
        #do something else with a and b
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to run `Aclass`'s get method:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self, a, b):
        print "I'm A, here's my arguments: %s, %s" % (a, b)


class B(A):
    def foo(self, a, b, c):
        super(B, self).foo(a, b)
        print "I'm B, here's that other argument: %s" % c
```

In practice:

```
In [9]: b = B()

In [10]: b.foo("cake", "pie", "beachball")
I'm A, here's my arguments: cake, pie
I'm B, here's that other argument: beachball
```